# Probability of at least $k$ consecutive heads after $n$ fair coin tosses

Tags: probability

I've seen some discussions on similar problems but they seem to be overly complex, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something. I obtained the following: $$P(n, k) = 1 - \left(\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}\right)^{n-k}$$ Since for any consecutive $k$ tosses the probability that at least one tails show up is $\frac{2^k-1}{2^k}$ and the total number of these $k$ - sequences is $n-k$, the formula should hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the fact that these events are not independent. (Also, but less important, there are $n-k+1$ possible places it could occur, not $n-k$; if $n=k$ there is still one possible place, etc.)

For example, take $k=2$ and $n=3$. Your formula (after correcting $n-k$ to $n-k+1$) gives $1-(3/4)^2=7/16$. However the actual probability is $3/8$, since you need the middle toss and at least one other to be heads.

What's going on here is that if the first consecutive pair aren't all heads, that increases the chance that the second toss was a tail, so increases the chance that the second pair also aren't all heads.